# swift UIDatePicker limit date range selection

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have a datepicker but i want to limit user selection of dates for e.g., only between 5th till 25th of every month. How can i limit the date selection? below code is used to display date selection.

```
var datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
datePicker.minimumDate = Date()
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
} else if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
}
datePicker.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: You can't do this with a `UIDatePicker` -- but it would be rather straight-forward to use a `UIPickerView` to emulate it ("wheels" style only).

Comment: Let me rephrase that comment... if you only want to **restrict** date selection, evaluate the selected date and, if it doesn't match your criteria, set the datePicker date to the nearest valid date. If you only want to **display** valid dates, you'll need to use a `UIPickerView` (or your own custom view).